# template argument deduction в конструкторе

Tags: c++

Есть пример простого рабочего кода, который определяет тип шаблона автоматически из параметра конструктора:

```
template <typename F>
struct func
{
   F f;
   func (F && f) : f (std::move(f)) {}
};

auto f = func ([] () {});  // OK
```

Теперь я хочу добавить в параметры шаблона еще один тип, который хочу явно указывать при создании объекта, но чтобы тип лямбды продолжал определяться автоматически:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
struct func
{
   F f;
   T t;
   func (F && f) : f (std::move(f)) {}
};

auto f = func<int> ([] () {});  // Ошибка
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
a.cpp:48:21: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
48 |    auto f = func<int> ([] () {});
```

Почему второй аргумент шаблона не выводится автоматически из аргумента конструктора?

Comment: Вывод аргументов из конструктора не осуществляется, когда в шаблоне уже указаны какие-то аргументы. И вместо `auto f = func ([] () {});` лучше писать `func f{[] () {}};`

Answer (score 1):

Если указать хотя бы один шаблонный аргумент для класса, то остальные перестанут выводиться.

Обычно делают так:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct A
{
    F func;
    A(tag<T>, F func) : func(std::move(func)) {}
};

A a(tag<int>{}, []{});
```

---

Еще учтите, что хоть вы и написали `&&`, встроенный вывод шаблонных аргументов классов не умеет в forwarding-ссылки.

Например, это не собирается:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct A
{
    A(tag<T>, F &&func) {}
};

auto l = []{};
A a(tag<int>{}, l);
```

`&&` тут работает как обычная rvalue-ссылка, и не принимает lvalue.

Либо передавайте `F` по значению, как я сделал выше, либо пишите свой deduction guide, вот так:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct A
{
    std::decay_t<F> func;
    A(tag<T>, F &&func) : func(std::forward<F>(func)) {}
};

template <typename T, typename F>
A(tag<T>, F &&) -> A<T, F>;

auto l = []{};
A a(tag<int>{}, l);
```

Обратите внимание на `std::forward` вместо `std::move`, и на `std::decay`.